# Silent Installation of "j2re-1_4_2_06-windows-i586-p.exe" on Vista Ultimate

Tags: java

`2re-1_4_2_06-windows-i586-p.exe` is not being silently install on Vista ultimate. I am using following command:

```
j2re-1_4_2_06-windows-i586-p.exe /S /v"/qn ADDLOCAL=ALL IEXPLORER=0 MOZILLA=0"
```

That command work fine on XP and NT. Kindly tell me, how to make silent j2re on Vista Ultimate.

Comment: You know that Java 1.4.2 has finished it's EOL transition period last October: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/ This means that it is not totally and utterly unsupported! If you can manage to upgrade your OS to Windows 7, I'm sure you could risk upgrading to a Java runtime that's actually supported.

Comment: THe 64bit Version of 1.4.2 for Windows only supported Itanium, so probably x32.

Comment: I am currently working on X32.

Answer (score 0):

On thing you can try is to start your command line (cmd.exe) with administrator rights.

1. Search the cmd.exe in your start menu
2. right click on the icon
3. choose "run as administrator"
4. Try to re-execute the second command